# How to make range iterators of objects to use with boost KMP?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I've seen the examples using strings, but am unsure of how to pass in objects using the KMP algorithm. I have a circular buffer defined as circular_buffer< pair< time_t, MyObj>> where MyObj is:

```
typedef struct MyObj 
{
    MyData data;
}

typedef struct MyData
{
    uint8_t ident[BYTE_COUNT];
}
```

I'm looking for a way to use the KMP algorithm to find MyObj.data.ident within the circulur_buffer of MyObj's. The time_t value is a timestamp where I only wish to search from the back of the CB to a given number of seconds backwards in the buffer (so not the entire buffer).

```
boost::algorithm::knuth_morris_pratt_search ( cb.rbegin (), 
    cb.rend (), unknown, unknown);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: okay, we know what the haystack looks like. What does the needle look like? You are very vague about that. You mention "find `.ident`" but also `time_t` - what exactly is the search _pattern_?

Comment: The search pattern was MyObj.data.ident, I'm comparing that w/ the same in the haystack. Thanks, I think I can eventually figure this out.

Comment: @Einder trhat really says nothing about what the needle (a) is (b) means. It it a full `ident` (of `BYTE_COUNT` positions)? Is it a fragment? Should it match across different map entries (is it logically a consecutive stream)? If not, why were you ever looking at KMP? I'm happy to see my answer helped, but really this question smells like **[X/Y problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)** from start to end.

Comment: I have a function that convertes bytes to hex, so I end up with a hex string of characters. So basically, this is the string I'm using to compare between MyObj's. If this string is the same (i.e., if it's in the container I'm searching, or not), then that should tell me what action I need to take. I'm not certain KMP is the best way to go as I'm still trying to figure out what is the best way to go.

Comment: Could be the XY prob. I like trying to solve it myself first and then refactoring with or without help after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the needle is a pattern that occurs in `ident`, here's a sketch:

- Hardcoded random seed for generating random binary data
- Hardcoded "needle" pattern: 0x1e 0x9a
- Looks in last 2 seconds (assuming increasing clock values)
- the `std::search` call can be easily replaced by a KMP call

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2839e87db6084674)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

std::mt19937 prng{ 0x4e9d45ad };

namespace {
    static constexpr auto BYTE_COUNT = 32;

    struct MyData { uint8_t ident[BYTE_COUNT]; };
    struct MyObj { MyData data; };
}

using Buf = boost::circular_buffer<std::pair<std::time_t, MyObj> >;

Buf generate();
time_t time_offset(int offset_seconds);

template <typename Needle> auto search_for(Buf const& haystack, Needle const& needle) {
    auto const threshold = time_offset(-2);

    auto ubound = std::upper_bound(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), threshold, [] (auto& a, auto& b) { return a <= b.first; });

    auto match  = std::find_if(ubound, haystack.end(), [&needle](auto& entry) {
            auto& ident = entry.second.data.ident;
            return std::end(ident) != std::search(
                    std::begin(ident), std::end(ident),
                    std::begin(needle), std::end(needle)
                );
            });

    return match;
}

int main() {
    auto haystack = generate();

    uint8_t needle[2] = { 0x1e, 0x9a };
    auto match = search_for(haystack, needle);

    if (haystack.end() != match)
    {
        auto tp = match->first;
        std::cout << "Matching entry at " << ctime(&tp);

        for (int ch : match->second.data.ident)
            std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << ch << " ";

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <functional>

Buf generate() {
    Buf cb(512);
    auto randchar = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, 255), prng);

    for (auto i = 0u; i < 32; i++) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(prng() % 500));

        cb.push_back({ time(NULL), {} });

        auto &ident = cb.back().second.data.ident;
        std::generate(std::begin(ident), std::end(ident), randchar);
    }

    return cb;
}

time_t time_offset(int offset_seconds) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm now_tm = *localtime(&now);
    struct tm then_tm = now_tm;
    then_tm.tm_sec += offset_seconds;

    return mktime(&then_tm); // normalize it
}
```

Prints:

```
Matching entry at Thu Sep 24 00:03:56 2015
0xb 0x5e 0xa3 0x5d 0x28 0x27 0xa5 0x34 0xa9 0x90 0x97 0x91 0xb2 0x8f 0x74 0xda 0x18 0xc 0x81 0x78 0xe 0x22 0x1e 0x9a 0xcf 0xa3 0x21 0x10 0xa9 0xfa 0xd1 0xe5
```

Note that the matching subsequence `0x1e 0x9a` appears.